Why when I use memcached as my Laravel session driver, csrf validation always fail?
I noticed when I set SESSION_DRIVER to other drivers like redis, everything works fine, but when it is memcached, my requests always fail because of CSRF token mismatch.
I went and looked Laravel's Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken middleware, or to be more accurate, Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken; I noticed all booleans are false in its condition
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (
            $this->isReading($request) ||
            $this->runningUnitTests() ||
            $this->inExceptArray($request) ||
            $this->tokensMatch($request)
        ) {
            return tap($next($request), function ($response) use ($request) {
                if ($this->shouldAddXsrfTokenCookie()) {
                    $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $response);
                }
            });
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException('CSRF token mismatch.');
    }

I went deeper, and looked at tokensMatch() method.
    protected function tokensMatch($request)
    {
        $token = $this->getTokenFromRequest($request);

        return is_string($request->session()->token()) &&
               is_string($token) &&
               hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
    }

I understood that when I used memcached as driver, $request->session()->token() and $this->getTokenFromRequest($request) mismatch. But why?
php-memcached is my memcached php extension

The problem is solved. I had installed memcached with docker image. After installation, you need to execute memcached binary file like below(daemond or not):
memcached -v -u www-data

I at least expected a single error. Don't know why Laravel was working fine without memcached being up!
